# inserting values for each of items of an enum field using Yii2 activeform

Tags: php, yii2

I have a `user` model and an `attachment` model.

**User**:

```
id    name     email         password_hash
--------------------------------------
1     Reza     reza@web.af   xxxxxxx
```

**Attachment**:

```
user_id    type(enum)   name
--------------------------------------
1          resume       fk4k34kdfmkg3.pdf
1          photo        59rg3kerfn3ju.jpg
1          nid          34kf2wkefclh0.jpg
```

I need to create the activeform for it and I am wondering what is the appropriate (best) way to create model fields for them. each time a new user is registered three rows of attachments will be inserted to the attachments table too. Of course the following activeform is not doing what i want. please help.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?=$form->field($user, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?=$form->field($user, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?=$form->field($user, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($attachment, 'type')->fileInput()->label('photo') ?>
<?= $form->field($attachment, 'type')->fileInput()->label('resume') ?>
<?= $form->field($attachment, 'type')->fileInput()->label('nid') ?>
..
..
```

Comment: i suggest you to change `attachment` table structure

Answer (score 1):

In your **model** define three public variable like

```
public $typePhoto;
public $typeResume;
public $typeNid;
```

then define **rules** like

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['typePhoto', 'typeResume', 'typeNid'], 'required'],
    ];
}
```

and then create **ActiveForm** like this

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?=$form->field($user, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?=$form->field($user, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?=$form->field($user, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($attachment, 'typePhoto')->fileInput()->label('photo') ?>
<?= $form->field($attachment, 'typeResume')->fileInput()->label('resume') ?>
<?= $form->field($attachment, 'typeNid')->fileInput()->label('nid') ?>
..
..
```

Refer [Creating Forms](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html)

Comment: Dear Vishub, unfortunately I do not have access to the table structure and I don't think they would agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think for that purpose you should use yii model form extended from yii\base\Model. It can provide columns different from database ones.

Here is the simplified example of form model that you need:

```
class LoginForm extends \yii\base\Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password_hash;
    public $type_resume;
    public $type_photo;
    public $type_nid;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        // define validation rules here
        ];
    }

    public function saveData() 
    {
         $userModel = new User();
         $userModel->name = $this->name;
         //and so on, save all user properties
         $userModel->save();

         $attachModel = new Attachment();
         $attachModel->type = 'resume'; //it better to use constant
         $attachModel->user_id = $userModel->id;
         $attachModel->name = ' '; //set the necessary value
         $attachModel->save();

         //and so on, save your attachment models for all types
    } 
}
```

So your ActiveForm should be something like this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?=$form->field($loginForm, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?=$form->field($loginForm, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?=$form->field($loginForm, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($loginForm, 'type_photo')->fileInput()->label('photo') ?>
<?= $form->field($loginForm, 'type_resume')->fileInput()->label('resume') ?>
<?= $form->field($loginForm, 'type_nid')->fileInput()->label('nid') ?>
..
```

In code above the $loginForm is object of LoginForm class. Use saveData method of LoginForm to save the data properly.

For more information about yii form models visit http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html